How much more energy is released by a nuclear bomb than is required to create it? (Or is it a net loss?)
It seems like it takes a pretty substantial amount of energy to make a nuclear bomb. If you’re building a U-235 device, you need to run a huge array of gas centrifuges. If you’re making a plutonium bomb, you need to run a nuclear reactor to create the plutonium. (I remember reading that in the Manhattan Project, a substantial fraction of the power generated by the Grand Coulee Dam was used to power the pumps to cool the Hanford B reactor.)
Then you have to factor in the energy required to mine the uranium out of the ground and extract it from its ore, transport it, etc.
Is there a way to roughly estimate the amount of energy required to build a nuclear bomb? How does it compare to the energy that’s released when the bomb is detonated?

A nuclear weapon is designed to be effective, not efficient.

@JonCuster Well, in nuclear power generation, the fuel generates more power than is required to get refine the fuel from ore, load the refined fuel into the reactor, and move spent fuel into storage. Whether the same is true for a bomb is an interesting question.

The Hanford N reactor was the only one that generated power (and had more optimized cooling), producing some 800 MW. That would run a lot of centrifuges to produce more enriched reactor fuel while also producing plutonium at no extra cost to energy consumption. Cooling of the B reactor was by overwhelming brute force of lots of water flowing through. But a nuclear weapon primary is quite inefficient in its utilization of the fuel.

Net energy required to build something probably can't be determined by physics alone, but wide knowledge of the whole industry and of efficiencies of all the steps would be needed. That energy today may be much smaller than in 1940's due to developments in nuclear industry. Maybe someone from nuclear industry can answer.

Also, modern nukes are thermonuclear and can be made to have 99% of the released energy from fusion fuel, not from plutonium or uranium. Thus the net energy released may be many times greater than energy released from
plutonium/uranium.

For what it's worth this article says "By mid-July [1945] the [Y-12] facility had produced slightly more than 50 kilograms [of enriched uranium]. By this time Y-12 had consumed about 1.6 billion kilowatt-hours of electricity, about 100 times the energy yielded by [...] Little Boy."

@JánLalinský - well, no, the fusion part is there to provide lots of energetic neutrons very rapidly to fission uranium (both 235 and, more importantly, 238). One D-T fusion yields one-tenth the energy of a uranium fission event.
